# What do these do in php regex?

Tags: php, regex

I found:

```
1 - $milk = preg_replace( "/(\(\s*)(.+?)(\s*\))/","",$milk);
2 - $milk = ereg_replace( "[^[:space:]A-Za-z0-9&_-]", "", $milk);
```

$milk is a large string about a paragraph say.

What do 1 and 2 do to $milk?

Also, ereg has been deprecated acording to php manual.  Can this be replaced with some other php in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 and 2 are part of expressions that evaporate, they do nothing valueable in this context.
 It amounts to:

```
1 - $milk = ("text");
```

The variable gets set to whatever the function returned. Then PHP will attempt another arithmetic operation, but throw the result away. It's basically `1 - 0;` on a line by itself, because the text string gets treated as zero.

Btw, `preg_replace` is already the newer alternative to `ereg_replace`. So only the second line needed to be adapted.